# access denied or repository not exported when download android source code

Tags: android, git, ubuntu

I am trying to download android_4.2_r1 source code. And I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed jdk 1.6, Python 2.7, Git..

I downloaded repo use this code "$ curl http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/downloads/detail?name=repo-1.12 ~/bin/repo" (Since the official one is forbidden in China... )

Anyway, I initiated repo successfully.

But when I try to 'repo sync' I meet the error:

```
brendon@brendon-Lenovo:~/android4.2/.repo$ repo sync
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /platform/abi/cpp.git
error: Cannot fetch platform/abi/cpp
```

Does Anyone know the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because some fetch link is forbidden in China...

We just need to choose the one that can be used here.

I recommend this one: `git://Android.git.linaro.org/`